# New to October - Raspberry installation

Tags: raspberry-pi3, octobercms

I have just designed a website with a 3rd party application that support October as CMS.

I would like to configure October in order to change the contents of some pages without having each time to modify and to reupload the site.

If I have understood correctly I need to install October in a server.

So my doubt is if I can install October in a server different from the server Hosting the site. I have a couple of Raspberry acting as a home web servers and I was thinking to install October there. Would it be a good idea or?

Thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

No, short answer is no because October is flat file system based CMS so, all changes will happen on file and reflected at front-end side

and if your hosting server and your October CMS install server is different , how you can update those files and reflect is changes.

if you install October CMS in  `home web servers` then how you pass files to your server hosting the site ?